# Geometry tab missing when importing obj files

Tags: obj

I could not find Geometry tab in obj import dialog in latest Blender (v3.4),
it was there in v3.0.
Since my model is generated dynamically, so sometimes I need to confirm vertex data in Blender, so Keep vertex order is important to me.

How can I get it back in latest version?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Looks as if it may have been removed after version 3.1. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/files/import_export/obj.html#importing) is the blender manual entry for version 3.2 where it's not mentioned.

Comment: Hi, @JohnEason, Thanks for your reply.
So I need to use blender below ver 3.1 if I want to use that feature, right?

Comment: Looking at the release notes for 3.1 it seems that the obj importer was rewritten in C++, presumably for speed. **However** I've just searched the addons in Preferences for "wavefront" and it looks as if you may be in luck! The old importer **is** still available, being shown as (legacy). If you enable that you get an extra entry at the bottom of the File > Import menu and the file selector for that does indeed still have the Geometry tab on it and that's in version 3.4! :^)

Comment: Hi, @JohnEason. You saved my life!
Yes, after enabling it, Geometry tab is live again.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnEason said in the comment, after enabling "Import-Export: Wavefront OBJ format (legacy)" in add-ons, a new wavefront(.obj)(legacy) menu is added and Geometry tab is back again using that new menu.

Hope this can help people who need that Geometry tab like me.

Thanks again for your help, @JohnEason.

Comment: Glad to help! Incidentally, it's worth noting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281240/how-do-i-batch-export-meshes-into-obj-files-non-legacy?noredirect=1#comment483260_281240 for future reference.

Comment: Thank you @JohnEason. it would be very helpful to me.