# How do I batch export meshes into .obj files (NON-LEGACY)

Tags: python, export, obj

When I try to batch export a series of meshes using the template python script, it turns them into Wavefront(.obj)(legacy) instead of the normal .obj

Even though normal .obj and legacy .obj have the same file type, they have different file sizes and contents. The legacy type of file doesn't work correctly in Roblox Studio when I import it, but the normal one does(which I tested manually). Thank you.

Here is the final code solved by scurest

```py
# exports each selected object into its own file

import bpy
import os

# export to blend file location
basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)

if not basedir:
    raise Exception("Blend file is not saved")

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selection:

    obj.select_set(True)

    # some exporters only use the active object
    view_layer.objects.active = obj

    name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
    fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)

    bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(filepath=fn + ".obj", export_selected_objects=True)

    # Can be used for multiple formats
    # bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d(filepath=fn + ".x3d", use_selection=True)

    obj.select_set(False)

    print("written:", fn)


view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)
```

Comment: It looks as if the legacy wavefront addon takes precedence over the newer built-in C++ one. Do you have both listed under File > Export? If so, I'd try unchecking the 'Import Export: Wavefront Obj Format (legacy)' entry in Preferences > Addons and see if that cures the problem. If not, I'm afraid I've no idea.

Comment: Thank you,sadly now it doesn't batch export at all, giving the error: 
"AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.export_scene.obj" error, could not be found".
This is a very specific case so I will export my objects manually for now

Comment: The new one is `bpy.ops.wm.obj_export()`, the legacy one is `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj()`. You can find this out by turning on Python Tooltips in the prefs, then hover over the menu to see the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tested and it works. Praise be to you