# Exporting an OBJ file as a batch? (most recent blender update)

Tags: export

I have around over 220+ pieces in my blender sessions for an art design that I would like to get SLA(resin printed) now in order to submit them to a person to do that I would need to submit individual files. Now if I export in the STL I can batch but the designs do not come out smooth. Now I believe that exporting in an OBJ is the smoothest?!>(plz correct me). I am not sure if I am able to export a batch file in OBJ or if there are any ways to export the 3D design as smooth as possible and in a batch. Please Help.

Comment: IMPORTANT ++==(While exporting to scale of blender session)

Comment: Hello, it shouldnt matter what file format you choose for the model smoothness. Maybe you may want to apply modifiers ?

Comment: If you want to try python https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281240/how-do-i-batch-export-meshes-into-obj-files-non-legacy